# Why am I getting this IndexOutOfBoundsException error?

Tags: java

hi so im currently trying to get past this error in my code, if anyone could explain where I went wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Lab07vst100SD
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
     
      System.out.println();
      int size = 10;
      School bhs = new School(size);
      System.out.println(bhs);
      System.out.println(bhs.linearSearch("Meg"));
      System.out.println(bhs.linearSearch("Sid"));
      System.out.println();
      bhs.selectionSort();
      System.out.println(bhs);
      System.out.println(bhs.binarySearch("Meg"));
      System.out.println(bhs.binarySearch("Sid"));
      System.out.println();
   }     
}

class School
{
   private ArrayList<Student> students;
   private int size;
   
   public School (int s) 
   {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>();
      size = s;
   }
   public void addData() 

   { 
      String [] name = {"Tom","Ann","Bob","Jan","Joe","Sue","Jay","Meg","Art","Deb"};
      int[] age = {21,34,18,45,27,19,30,38,40,35};
      double[] gpa = {1.685,3.875,2.5,4.0,2.975,3.225,3.65,2.0,3.999,2.125};
     
       
      for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
      {
         students.add(new Student(name[i], age[i], gpa[i]));  
      }
      size = students.size(); 
   } 
 
   
   public void selectionSort () 

   {
      for(int h = 0; h < students.size(); h++)
      {
         int index = h;
         Student least = students.get(h);
         for (int t = 0; t < size; t++) {
            if (students.get(t).equals(least)) {
               least = students.get(t);
               index = t;
            }
            Student temp = students.get(h);
            students.set(h, least);
            students.set(t, temp);
         }
      }
       
   }

   public int linearSearch (String str)
   { 
   // new arraylist 
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (int q = 0; q < size; q++) {
         names.add(students.get(q).getName());
      }
      //comparison 
      for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
         if (names.get(y).equals(str))
            return y;
      }
      return -1;
   };    
   public int binarySearch (String str) {
   // new arraylist and variables
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
      Boolean found = false;
      int lo = 0;
      int hi = size;
      int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
      //for loop for to transverse the array.
      for (int m = 0; m < size; m++) {
         names.add(students.get(m).getName());
      }
      while (lo <= hi && !found) {
         if (names.get(mid).compareTo(str) == 0)
         {
            found = true;
            return mid;
         }
         if (names.get(mid).compareTo(str) < 0) {
            lo = mid + 1;
            mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
         }
         else {
            hi = mid -1;
            mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
         }
      }
      if (found)
         return mid;
      else
         return -1;  
   }
   public String toString() { 
      String temp = "";
      for (int s = 0; s < students.size(); s++) {
         temp += students.get(s);
      }
      return temp; 
   }
}
```

also, I should mention this uses the student class.

here

```
public class Student
{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private double gpa;
   
   public Student (String n, int a, double g)
   {
      name = n;
      age = a;
      gpa = g;
   }
   
   public String getName() { 
      return name; }  
   public int getAge()     { 
      return age; }  
   public double getGPA()  { 
      return gpa; }
      
   public String toString()
   {
      String temp = name + "  " + age + "  " + gpa + "\n";
      return temp;
   }
}
```

the school class calls to the student class.

this is what comes back.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at School.linearSearch(Lab07vst100SD.java:78)
    at Lab07vst100SD.main(Lab07vst100SD.java:16)
```

I'm completely confused on why this is happening, I think it may have to do with the  ArrayList, other than that, I'm not sure.
please help, and thank you

p.s. I'm new so please bear with my horrible format.

Comment: Please first highlight the line from which the exception is thrown and examine the parameters passed to the method that throws the exception. The reason is that you are passsing a value that exceeds the size of the list so clearly you are passing a parameter that is not compared to the length of the list. Go find out what the parameter is and what it's value is.

Comment: You're not adding  the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need call `addData`:

```java
public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println();
        int size = 10;
        School bhs = new School(size);
        bhs.addData(); // here 
        System.out.println(bhs);
        System.out.println(bhs.linearSearch("Meg"));
        System.out.println(bhs.linearSearch("Sid"));
        System.out.println();
        bhs.selectionSort();
        System.out.println(bhs);
        System.out.println(bhs.binarySearch("Meg"));
        System.out.println(bhs.binarySearch("Sid"));
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Also, use `students.size()` to get the size of your list. There's very little point in storing a size when the `ArrayList` does that for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
...
class School
{
   private ArrayList<Student> students;
   private int size;
   
   public School (int s) 
   {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>(); // Here, it can throw IndexOutOfBoundsException 
      size = s;
   }
...
```

Please see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm

The capacity of `ArrayList` must be initialized before `ArrayList.add` method
.